# Uncaught reference: function not defined

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom-events

I am working on a small project. I have created a PHP page in that as soon as a button in clicked a function named `sendMessage` should get executed but instead it is showing me uncaught reference error.

My error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError:sendMessage is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick
> line 29.  At last onclick call

Here is my js file named chat.js:

```
function btn() {
    var s = document.getElementById("chat_id");
    var o = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("chat");
    x[0].style.display = "inline-block";
    x[1].innerHTML = "<span>" + "Chatting with:" + o + "<span>";
}

function sendMessage() {
    var msg = document.getElementById("msg").value;
    if (msg.length === 0 || msg === "") {
        alert("please enter some message");
        return;
    }

    var sender = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var sendto = document.getElementById("chat_id").options[document.getElementById("chat_id").selectedIndex].value;

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 400) {
            document.getElementById("chat_logs").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
        xhttp.open('GET', 'send_messages.php?sender=' + sender + 'sendto=' + sendto + 'message=' + msg, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
}


function test() {
    alert("lol");
}
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php
    include ('db.php');
   session_start();
  if(empty($_SESSION['user_logs'])){ //check if user session is set
  header('Location:login.php'); //redirect to login page if user session is not set
  }
 ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <title>chat box</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="chat.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chatbox.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container cont">
      <p>
        <a href="logout.php">Logout <?php echo $_SESSION['user_logs']; ?></a>
      </p>
      <input type="hidden" id="username" value=<?php echo $_SESSION[ 'user_logs']; ?>>

      <p>
        <label for="chatwith">Chat with:</label>
        <select name="chat_user" id="chat_id" class="selectpicker">
          <option disabled selected>select</option>
          <?php
    $current_user=$_SESSION['user_logs'];

    $rows=mysqli_query($con,"select username from users where username!='".$current_user."'");
        while($rowsArray=mysqli_fetch_array($rows)):
    ?>
            <option value=<?php echo $rowsArray[ 'username']; ?>>
              <?php echo $rowsArray['username']; ?>
            </option>
            <?php endwhile;?>
        </select>
        <input type="button" id="btn_chat" name="toggle" value="chat" class="btn btn-info" onclick="btn();" />
        <div id="chat_div" class="chat">
          <span class="chat">Chatting with:</span>
          <div class="chat" id="chat_logs"></div>
          <div class="chat" id="input">
            <textarea value="" placeholder="Enter message" id="msg" name="message" required maxlength="150"></textarea>
            <input type="button" id="btn-send" class="btn btn-primary" value="send" onclick="sendMessage();" />
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: The very least you can do is include the actual error message and line number.

Comment: Often it is useful to show the rendered HTML and THEN you can see where your PHP fails to render properly - and makes it easier for others to gain insight into the failure.

Comment: value attribute of hidden input is correct ..it is showing value="rohit"..which is the correct username

Comment: To restate, it SEEMS like the `onclick` in here does not find the function: `<input type="button" id="btn-send" class="btn btn-primary" value="send" onclick="sendMessage();" />` question is, why is that? Script is in the header so that would not appear to be the issue, or is it?  Does that script in your browser load? it says it is in the same location as the page.

Comment: other functions in the same js file are working

Comment: got it..it was my xamp server which was not saving the changes in my chat.js file.Due to which my sendMessage function doesnt existed.But now it's resolved.Thanks everyone

Comment: Are you sure?  Your sendMessage function is missing a closing } character.